# Aws write capacity Calculator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I entered the following values into the calculator, and the price I got was confusing.

Dataset size 1GB
Item Size: 1KB
RCU 200 
Eventually consistent

then for WCU I entered 2, then entered 20 and the price is the same. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You get 25 WCU and 25 RCU for free. The price only starts increasing after 25.

Comment: Is that for every table by the way?

Comment: No, thats in total.